# How to split a list index range in python?

Tags: python, list

Given a list:

```
['x','y',1,2,'b','l',3,'z']
```

I want to split the list by given illicit characters,
e.g  the given characters are 'y' and 'b', I want to get the indexation: `[0,2:3,5:]`

How can I do so?

Comment: What did you try so far? Some sort of for loop in conjunction with if/else statements will be a good starting point here.

Comment: What? Do you want to return a string `[0,2:3,5:]`?

Comment: can you elaborate your question to get it more clear? what should this `[0,2:3,5:]` mean?

Comment: I want to access other lists by a structure of one list. this is why I need to get the indexation. probably the list values you copied should be stored as strings, but thats not the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can group your list by the condition of whether the element is in your *illicit characters* and then extract the corresponding index for each group:

```
from itertools import groupby
charList = ['y', 'b']
[[i[0] for i in g] for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda x: x[1] in charList) if not k]

# [[0], [2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Another way to extract the index from each group here:

```
[list(zip(*g))[0] for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda x: x[1] in charList) if not k]

# [(0,), (2, 3), (5, 6, 7)]
```